# How to forward an "example.com" to "www.example.com"?

Tags: domains, url, domain-forwarding

I am using GoDaddy for my domains. Lately I've noticed that none of my `example.com` addresses are mapping to the server correctly. I used "Forward" option from Domain Manager and forwarded it to `www.example.com`, but it still is not working after a week.

I don't have access to the server, so I can't use redirecting or URL rewriting. What else can I do about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is a DNS record issue.

Make sure that you have a DNS A record called `domain.com`, and that it's pointing at your server. A lot of the time, people only have the `www.domain.com`. A record believing you have to put www. before all domain names. However, people like myself never bother typing www., so we end up putting "domain.com".

Comment: This is what I do every time I have this issue. It's one of the first things I set up.

Comment: The site I am pointing to only gives me a CNAME record, no A records. I tried creating 2 CNAME records -- one for www and the other for domain.com -- pointing to the same server, but didn't work. :-(

Comment: There are several types of domain records. You need to create two A records, not CNAME.

Comment: Creating a `CNAME` record for the domain itself has a bunch of risks and is advised against.  I just researched this a few days ago myself: http://support.simpledns.com/kb/a94/why-cant-i-create-a-cname-record-for-the-zone-name-itself.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**Why is .www deprecated?**

> In order to answer this question, we
>   must first recall the definition of
>   WWW:
>
> World Wide Web: n. Abbr. WWW
>
> 1) The complete set of documents
>   residing on all Internet servers that
>   use the HTTP protocol, accessible to
>   users via a simple point-and-click
>   system.
>
> 2) n : a collection of internet sites
>   that offer text and graphics and sound
>   and animation resources through the
>   hypertext transfer protocol. By
>   default, all popular Web browsers
>   assume the HTTP protocol. In doing so,
>   the software prepends the 'http://'
>   onto the requested URL and
>   automatically connect to the HTTP
>   server on port 80. Why then do many
>   servers require their websites to
>   communicate through the www subdomain?
>   Mail servers do not require you to
>   send emails to
>   recipient@mail.domain.com. Likewise,
>   web servers should allow access to
>   their pages though the main domain
>   unless a particular subdomain is
>   required.
>
> Succinctly, use of the www subdomain
>   is redundant and time consuming to
>   communicate. The internet, media, and
>   society are all better off without it.
>
> Using the links at the top of the
>   page, you may view recently validated
>   domains as well as submit domains for
>   real-time validation.

Taken from no-www.org

Comment: +1 because this is a very good point to make and cites 3rd party research.  However, this does not actually answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yoursite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Put that in your .htaccess file.
Also, if you don't have a line which states "RewriteEngine On" in your .htaccess, make sure you put one like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yoursite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: He said he can't use URL rewriting.

Comment: Oh! My bad, sorry :(